# How common is nasal assimilation before stops?

Tags: phonology

It's been a bit hard for me to find content on this, I know it's common and read it's nearly universal, with exceptions like Russian ng mk.

Comment: You mean, data on how common it is for nasals to assimilate to the place of articulation of the following consonant?

Comment: That applies too, but specifically I'm looking for facts regarding how languages deal with it, as in Russian not doing it afaik. [my English is not good at all, writing questions takes me a lot of times for no satisfying output, so the question is probably not clear]

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all facts pertaining to nasal assimilation? If not, what exactly is it you want to know. There are unassimilated sequences in English, like Hamden: what do you mean, how do we "deal" with it? You can't just ask for "all facts". The question needs to be made vastly more specific.

Comment: Ok, I understand... So, what Draconis wrote "data on how common it is for nasals to assimilate to the place of articulation of the following consonant" is a good option. I Will rewrite the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general belief among phonologists that (regressive) nasal place assimilation is very common: we can usually cite a half-dozen off the top of our individual heads. I think I could cite a few thousand examples, most of which would be Austronesian or Niger-Congo languages. Because there are so many Niger-Congo and Austronesian languages, I would probably be correct in saying that most languages have such assimilation.

However, if you're looking for an actually scientific answer, the answer is that nobody knows. The problem is not limited to just place assimilation, but rather follows from the fact that we don't have a sufficient database on what languages do that we can consult, and what we know is skewed in favor of certain languages (those that we, individually, know about). The only South American language that I know anything about is Quechua, which has such assimilation, and I honestly can't say whether it is "common" in South American languages.

The other problem is sorting languages as to degree of assimilation. For instance, all Bantu languages (as far as I know) have some place-assimilation (certain nasals always assimilate), but some languages also have un-assimilated nasals (usually from reduction of /mu/), for example Swahili *um̩saidie* "you should help him". Keley-i (an Austronesian language) has a couple of nasal place assimilation processes, but /m/ does not assimilate, and some outputs of vowel-deletion create unassimilated NC sequences. We know even less about how common it is to have *universal* place assimilation in a language, versus some non-assimilated cases.

It would be a great lifetime project for someone to construct a database whereby we could answer such questions about "how common", but unfortunately all we have to go on is personal experience.

Answer (score 4):

The name "nasal assimilation" may be misleading.  Is it the nasality of a consonant that makes it especially subject to regressive place assimilation? In English, not only does alveolar nasal stop n assimilate, but alveolar non-nasal stops d and t also assimilate in position to a following stop.  Maybe it is the fact that n is a stop that causes it to assimilate, rather than that n is a nasal.

The general principle dubbed the "law of similarity" (by David Stampe, which he attributes to Paul Passy, founder of the IPA) requires that when a segment is affected by a nearby sound, it must also be affected correspondingly by more similar sounds.  This suggests that English regressive assimilation affects n before a stop because n is a stop, not because n is a nasal.